# How to reduce an if statement and pass multiple values to Contains?

Tags: c#

Lets say I want to loop trough all the files in a directory and if the file has an extension of an image format such as jpeg, bmp, or png, I want to copy the file to another directory.  Is there a way I can check for all image extensions without chaining `||` together?  Here is an example:

Instead of:

```
if(file.Extension == ".jpg" || 
     file.Extension == ".jpeg" || 
     file.Extension == ".bmp" || 
     file.Extension == ".png")
            //Copy To Image directory
```

Can I do something like:

`if (file.Extension.Contains(...)).`

I know Contains exists, but it does not take an array of values (extensions in this case)

Comment: Have you considered a switch statement? Slightly cleaner than the || operators.

Comment: Yes, I have considered a switch, but since there aren't too many popular image formats, I thought it was a toss up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string>validExtensions = new List<string>(){".jpg", ".jpeg" /* rest go here */ };
if(validExtensions.Contains(myFilenameExension))
{...}
```

If you have a LOT of extensions I'd switch it from a List to a HashSet, but for a small number of values (i.e. 4) a List will be either the same or quicker.

Comment: This was what I was thinking I had to do, but was wondering if I could skip creating the validExtensions object.

Comment: Oof, ninja'd by about 20 seconds.

Comment: You can create the collection anonymously inline, but its more efficient not to.

Comment: @Xaisoft You could create an anonymous inline array, and it would be less code, but assuming this is run in a loop you want to do this instead.

Comment: @Servy - Can you do an example and explain what you mean by anonymous inline array?

Comment: @Xaisoft One of the other answers uses it.  As I said, you probably don't want to do it.  You'll be re-creating the structure every time the code is called, and it's not *that* much less code.

Comment: Don't forget that this way is case sensitive!

Answer (score 2):

Make a collection class, like this:

```
List<string> validExtensions = new List<string>()
{
     ".jpg",
     ".jpeg",
     ".bmp",
     ".png"
};
```

then do:

```
if (validExtensions.Any(ext=>file.Extension.Contains(ext)))
{
     //Do code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain what Any does here?

Comment: Any will return true if your file contains at least one of the extensions in your validExtensions collection.

Comment: OK.  I am curious as to how some of you guys come up with the answers so quick.  I can hardly type that fast :)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> extensions=new List<string>()
extensions.Add("jpg");
extensions.Add("png");
extensions.Add("mbp");

if(extensions.Contains(file.Extension)
{
 //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if (file.Extension.Contains(...))

You want the opposite:

```
if(new [] {".jpg", /* etc */ ".png"}.Contains(file.Extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{

}
```

This is a LINQ method, so make sure you have a `using System.Linq` somewhere. Also, I pass a comparer so that the case is ignored. It seems like for what you are doing, case sensitivity is not something you want.

Comment: @Xaisoft, well, I don't think "anonymous inline array" is the right terminology for it, it's just an array declaration that isn't being assigned to a local, but yes I think that is the general idea. You can always pull it up to a local or field if you need to.